# Child component transmit parameter to parent

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I want NodeComponent to transmit the parameter to the LayoutComponent.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: IndexComponent
    }, {
      path: 'node/:nodeId',
      component: NodeComponent
    }]
  }];
```

Comment: What parameter you want to be transmited? Can you give us more details?

Comment: title,  button event,         LayoutComponent includes functions of returning and saving editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `LayoutComponent` has the `<router-outlet>` placeholder that will serve you the proper component based on the router.

You can't send an `@Output` from the NodeComponent to the LayoutComponent in this case, but you can share the data via a `service` easily.

Create a `service` that will keep your `Node` variables / logic and update the data from the `NodeComponent`. This way, the `LayoutComponent` will be able to read it.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

    // Feel free to define observables, other variables or object
    nodeTitle: string;
    nodeBtnEvent: Event;

    setNodeData(nodeTitle, event, ...){
        // Assign the variables or do something
    }     

    getNodeData() {
       return { 
           nodeTitle,
           nodeBtnEvent
       }
    }

    constructor() {}

}
```

Use the setter to add the data from the `NodeComponent` and the getter to retrieve the data from the `LayoutComponent`.

Good luck!